# safe to call MapsInitializer.initialize(Context) several times

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

The question is simple:
Is it safe to call `MapsInitializer.initialize(Context);` several times without an exception being thrown for 'double-loading' the maps API

Comment: Is there any reason at all to call it? After your acquire reference to `GoogleMap` object, the library is initialized.

Comment: The problem is that I am getting a null ``GoogleMap`` but I'm not sure why

Comment: This can happen for several reasons. Best to start with the docs [about `GoogleMap` object availability verification](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#verify_map_availability) or asking a question regarding this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It may be safe but it is not required. see detailed description [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapsInitializer) it says:

> If you are using MapFragment or MapView and have already obtained a
> (non-null) GoogleMap by calling getMap() on either of these classes,
> then you do not need to worry about this class. See the sample
> application for some examples.

But as you said, you are getting null reference, you should check and resolve why it's returning null else it might return null again on your next call.